# Unique question about packing problem

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, density-function, combinatorial-geometry, packing-problem

I added the related pages from part 3 of the book: combinatorial geometry by János Pach,Pankaj K.Agarwal (1995) (which is not available on net so I added them as pictures).

> A. Prove that one can always find a packing $Ç$ of the plane with congruent copies of a convex disc $C$ whose density $d(Ç,R^2)$ exists and is equal to $\delta(C)$.
> Similarly show that there is a Lattice packing $Ç$ with $d(Ç,R^2)=\delta_L(C)$.

> B.construct a packing $Ç$ of unit discs and two convex discs $P,P'$ such that $lim_{r\to \infty} d(Ç,P(r)) \neq lim_{r\to \infty} d(Ç,P'(r))$.

Hints:
Part A:To prove the first statement, construct a packing $C_n$ of congruent copies of $C$ in the disc $D(n)$ with density $d(C_n,D(n))\geq \delta(C)-O(1)/n$

For every n choose a subsequence $n_1,n_2,...$ such that $C_{n_i}$ converges when restricted to $D(1)$ as $i\to \infty$ .
From this choose a subsequence for which $C_n$ converges when restricted to $D(2)$ and so on.
Show that the limit packing meets the requirements.

For part B: Let $Ç$ be the densest packing of unit discs in a cone.
Choose $P$ and $P'$ to be circular disc and a regular triangle respectively.

Can you kindly help me to understand this (I'm a beginner in this field).

1.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k1mz.jpg)

2.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEdCp.jpg)

3.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhhvM.jpg)

4.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIVsz.jpg)

5.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2O4m.jpg)

6.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuXvX.jpg)

Many thanks.

Comment: I deleted the tag "covering-spaces" because this has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Is there specific meaning for the term 'convex disc?' I was under the impression all discs are convex.

Comment: Hi @William a convex disc is defined in this book as a convex, compact set with non-empty interior.

Comment: @Usermat What does $P(r)$ mean? It makes sense if $P$ is a bona fide disc with a radius, but if it's just a compact convex set with nonempty interior then I don't know what $r$ means.

Comment: @William , $P(r)$ is a  convex disc with a radius $r$ (similar to $D(r)$ in page 2 i guess)

Comment: @Usermat What is the radius of a convex disc? Any regular $n$-gon is a convex disc, according to the definition of the textbook, but I am unclear on what the radius of an $n$-gon is. Is it minimum distance from the center of mass to the boundary?

Comment: @Usermat Two things: One, the hint for (A) suggests I misinterpreted it. I mixed the quantifiers-- it seems that it's not asking to find a packing $C$ which satisfies the properties. Instead, it's asking that given any convex disc $C$, construct a packing. I'll see what I can cook up. Two, I still don't know what $P(r)$ means, but the hint makes me think that if you take any convex cone with angle $\pi/3$, pack it optimally, and then take a disc and take a regular triangle as your two regions, the first's density will go to $0$, and the second to $1$. But I still don't know what $P(r)$ is.

Comment: Thank you @William P(r) is a convex disc with radius $r$ (P'(r) another convex disc with radius $r$) and we can choose each one as the hint suggests  . In part B my problem is that I am not sure how to apply this formally, showing that the limits are different.

Comment: @Usermat Notice that if your cone (with angle $\pi/3$) starts as the origin and is packed, then letting $P(r)$ be a disc with center at the origin and radius $r$, then the density of that packing will only ever be at most $1/6$. If you can show that the density of your equilateral triangle with vertex at the origin has density $>1/6$, you're done.

Comment: @William it is hard for me to imagine this, I don't see the computation (in my brain), i thought to use the definition of density but I could not reach the result :/. In part A do you have any idea how to finish it by using the hint? (Sorry but this question was tiring for me)

Comment: @Usermat Don't apologize--- these are not obvious questions (just look at how many questions I had to ask, and those were just the definitions). I'll take a close look when I can, likely later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding another answer, since my first is already pretty dense and I think it would be contextually useful to leave it up--- at least to make the comments make sense. If this is a StackExchange faux pas, apologies.

**Lemma**: Fix some convex disc $C$ and $R \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Then there is a packing $P$ which achieves an arbitrary density between $0$ and $\delta(C)$. That is to say, there is a packing $P$ so that $d(P,R) = r \in \mathbb{R}$, where $0 \leqslant r \leqslant \delta(C)$.

There are many ways to prove this, but I think if you want to make this rigorous a separation into cases and then IVT via translating a specific copy of $C$ through the boundary to increase density.

**Proof of A**:

Fix some convex disc $C$, and create an infinite family of packings $C_n$ so that:

$$d(C_n, D(n)) \geqslant \delta(C) - \frac{O(1)}{n}$$

for each $n$. Such a construction is justified by the lemma, since $O(1)/n > 0$. Moreover, the interval $[0,A(D(n))]$ is compact, so we choose a subsequence which converges in $D(1)$, then one which converges in $D(2)$ *from that subsequence*, and so on forever. Now let:

$$P = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} C^\ast_n$$

Where $C^\ast_n$ is the limiting sequence. I claim that $P$ is our desired packing. Indeed:

$$\delta(C) \geqslant \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(C^\ast_n, D(n)) \geqslant \delta(C) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{O(1)}{n}$$

since the limiting sequence converges in all $D(n)$ and has the bounds in all $D(n)$. As $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} O(1)/n$ goes to $0$, we have what we desired.

See if you can formulate something for the lattice packing.

**Proof of B**:

Fix our region $Q$ a convex cone of angle $\pi/3$ whose vertex is at the origin, and let $P$ be the densest packing of $Q$ with unit discs.

Then letting $P(r)$ be the disc $d(0,x) \leqslant r$, we can see immediately that $d(P,P(r)) \leqslant 1/6$ for large $r$.

Now let $P'(r)$ be an equilateral triangle with vertex at the origin and two legs on the boundary of $Q$. Since the angle of $Q$ is $\pi/3$, $P'(r)$ will always be in $Q$, and as this is the densest packing, it follows that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(P,P'(r)) = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{12}}$$

by the results mentioned in the textbook.

As $\pi/\sqrt{12} > 1/6$, their densities as $r \rightarrow \infty$ are different.

EDIT: Here is an image of the cone and the disc.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @William ,it makes a lot of sense. Only some things: In part A : 1. I am not sure how to prove the lemma, is it enough to say that the density is always ≥0 and use the definition of δ(C) ? , 2. For the lattice packing I would be glad to see how the proof works (since the hint only mentioned to use this mefhos for packing). In part B: Can you please add a drawing if is it possible , i don't understand where must the angle $\pi/3$ be located... ,And In the end you're using the Thue's theorem because it is a special case of it where unit discs is like "circles"?

Comment: For A, I would prove it by starting with a maximal packing that attains $\delta(C)$, then noting that translating convex discs apart defines a continuous function mapping the packing to the density. It's not immediate to me that there is a result that implies this, but there might be. Regardless, once continuity is established the IVT gives us our result. What does the book define as a 'lattice?' Depending on the definition the proof may differ. For B: do you know what a convex cone is?

Comment: Hi @william I read the definition of a convex cone from wikipedia pag, which is a closed set under transformations of the form $ax+by$ where a and b are constants and $x,y\in$ the cone. Can you please tell me in part B how to accomplish my drawing with the convex cone ( why we choose specifically to work with a cone and choose P to be a disc), how the inequality *d(P,P(r))≤1/6* is concluded by computations

Comment: The reason *why* we chose a convex cone of angle $\pi/3$ (the direction it opens out into is irrelevant) is because if we set an equilateral triangle with a vertex at the origin of the cone, no matter how much we 'grow' the equilateral triangle (that is, increase its diameter while maintaining similarity), it will always be inside of the cone. Hence the density of the limit of the triangle will be the density of the cone. On the other hand, if we let our convex disc be an actual disc, we notice that the cone is $1/6$ of the plane, so the density of the limit is at most $1/6$.

Comment: Yes, but can this be calculated by the density definition/formula (I still could not see how 1/6 is generated, i.e. why the cone is 1/6 of the plane) ? Is the disc intersect  the cone?

Comment: I have included a picture. The cone is $1/6$th of the plane because it has an interior angle of $\pi/3$, so 6 of the cones, each rotated $\pi/3$ angles, span $\mathbb{R}^2$. The highest density possible for any packing is $1$, so the highest density of the packing of the cone is $1$, hence the density of the packing of the cone in the disc is always at most $1/6$.

Comment: Thanks! Just want to ask, is our cone "infinite" , i mean that it starts from the origin but is not restricted in the plane?  And that is why six copies of it can span the whole plane. @william

Comment: @Usermat That is indeed why. A convex cone is equivalently considered as a linear cone (i.e., a subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ where if $x \in S$, then $\alpha s \in S$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$) that is closed under addition. Then the cone *must* be infinite or else there would be some upper bound on the scalar multiples, which we know is not the case as $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I'm leaving this post as context. See my comment to Usermat about my mistake.

For A:

I assume you have verified all of the results on the pages, or else are comfortable using them.

Note that page 5 gives us $$\delta(P) = \max_{P}d(P,\mathbb{R}^2)$$

for $P$ a packing. Hence for any packing $P$, it follows that $d(P,\mathbb{R}^2) \leqslant \delta(P)$. We wish to find a packing $X$ which satisfies $d(X,\mathbb{R}^2) \geqslant \delta(X)$, which will prove the result. This implies we need an optimal packing, which the textbook has supplied us with in the form of the packing in Figure 3.1. After all, the result of Thue says that $\overline{d}(P,\mathbb{R}^2) \leqslant \pi/\sqrt{12}$ for any packing, and so $d(P,\mathbb{R}^2) \leqslant d(X,\mathbb{R}^2) = \pi/\sqrt{12}$ for the greatest density packing $X$. Then $\max_Pd(P,\mathbb{R}^2) \leqslant d(X,\mathbb{R}^2)$ follows from this inequality holding for all $P$ packings, which is the reverse inequality we sought to show.

The second result of A follows from Corollary 3.6.

EDIT: This was a proof for discs in the normal usage of the term. The response to my comment in the post has a *convex disc* defined as a convex compact set with nonempty interior, so the proof does not strictly apply. In particular, the step where we show that $X$ is maximal no longer counts, because I chose a circle packing.

In general, I think that a packing of centrally symmetric hexagons $H$ will suffice. In fact, as this tiles the plane then the density will be 1, hence is easily seen to be maximal.

SECOND EDIT (In response to OP): Here is how I would write the proof.

Let $H$ be a collection of centrally symmetric hexagons which tile the plane. We wish to show:

$$d(H,R^2) = \delta(H)$$

which we will demonstrate via double inclusion (this method has many names).

The first direction is to show $d(H,R^2) \leqslant \delta(H)$. Indeed, it can be shown that $\delta(H) = \max d(H, R^2)$, where the maximum ranges over all packings with the elements of our packing. As our particular packing $H$ is one such packing, its density is at most $\delta(H)$.

The second direction is to show $d(H, R^2) \geqslant \delta(H)$. Here the choice of $H$ is relevant (notice that it was not used in the first direction), and in fact since $H$ is a plane tiling, the density of $H$ is $1$. It is easy to see that $d(Q,R^2)$ for any packing $Q$ is bounded above by $1$, hence $\delta(Q) \leqslant 1$ for any such collection of convex discs. Picking $H$ in particular, it follows that $\delta(H) \leqslant 1 = d(H, R^2)$.

Then as $d(H,R^2) \leqslant \delta(H) \leqslant d(H,R^2)$, by double inclusion we have what we wished to prove.

For a lattice packing, we note that since the elements of $H$ regularly tile the plane, the packing $H$ forms a lattice packing as well, and by Corollary 3.6, $\delta(H) = \delta_L(H)$. Hence:

$$d(H,R^2) = \delta(H) = \delta_L(H)$$

which is what we had to show.

Comment: Hi @William, thanks!:) For part A the other part: from page 5 $\delta_L(P)=d(P,R^2)$ where $P$ is a lattice packing.This for any lattice packing P: $d(P,R^2)\leq \delta_L(P)$. For the other inequality, we aim to find a lattice packing $X$ such that $d(X,R^2)\geq \delta_L(X)$. If $X$ is alattice packing of congruent copies of centrally symmetric convex disc ($c$) then by corollary 3.6 we get that: $\delta(X)=\delta_L(X)$ but how then to conclude the needed inequality?

Comment: @Usermat First of all, see my edit. I wrote a proof for discs in the normal usage. However, the same proof technique should apply for *convex discs* as the textbook defines them. In response to your comment: if you show the first equality for your packing $H$, provided you chose your packing shape to be centrally symmetric, then Corollary 3.6 applies, giving $d(H,R^2) = \delta(H) = \delta_L(H)$, where the first equality is the one you just proved, and the second is from the corollary.

Comment: @Usermat Notice that 3.4 is an upper bound, not equality. This affects both of your proofs. I wrote a proof in a second edit of my post, so you can examine how it is different and how I justified the statements.